# How to query a graph while mutation is happening in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is it possible to query a graph while mutation is happening in Memgraph? What is the best practice to update a graph graph while the read operation is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do both writes and reads simultaneously in Memgraph, because it uses MVCC mechanism which allows for execution modes where readers never block writers. More information can be found on [Memgraph docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/fundamentals/transactions) on transactions and isolation levels.